# Are these temperatures alright?

Tags: macbook-pro, temperature

I have bought a new macbook pro retina 15(the latest 2014 model) with dedicated graphic card couple of days ago, and not ever having a mac before, it feels extremely hot to me.

I've installed istats to check what the temperatures are like and it indeed seems quite high to me, and that is while not doing any extensive work, and just having a browser, airmail, st3 and slack open. The fans are not really loud or anything, so they don't seem to be running too fast..

Should I be worried?

..and I can imagine you get a lot of these temperature questions, so sorry for another one.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking for this exact question. Just got a brand new MBP, latest gen, 15 in with dedecated graphics card about a week ago. I was running games on it for most of its use, upon which a hot temperature is expected, but now I am running just chrome and skype and the laptop is continuing to burn up on my lap. I am used to MBPs before and have had them for years, so know what a normal temperature for them is while not running intensive programs (such as a game or some development environments)

On top of that, it does not seem like the fans are running at the appropriate times at all. I hear them spin up for 10 minutes or so, then seem to just give up after that letting it continue to get hot.

Right now, just with skype and Chrome open, it is running at 85-90C, which is way too hot to be acceptable. I am not very close to an apple store so would hate to take it in if this is normal, would like to hear what others say before making that trip.

Comment: couple of things I found out.. chrome + flash(like youtube or twitch) means insta high temperatures due to google chrome helper using buttload of cpu, issues that's apparently been around for ages and it was not fixed yet(https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/LfBqIlfFoSo), same happens with lots of other apps apparently(like guild wars 2 installer or popcorn time :P ), but the reason why it went crazy in my case was crash reporting, some apps were crashing and trying to start all the time, which again caused hude cpu load and in return high temps. Solved by reinstalling os.

Comment: I'm so flippin disappointed with this piece of overpriced shizz..